# Configure RestTemplate for HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler per message

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, resttemplate

I am working on a spring integration project where I am creating outbound gateway using **HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler** class. I want to execute different APIs which are authenticated using bearer authentication tokens using single gateway. I have different RestTemplate configured to handle each type of message.

I could not find how to configure restTemplate per message basis using this class. This class only accepts restTemplate at construction time.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/http/outbound/HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.html

For now, I have created custom gateway class by extended **AbstractHttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler** which is parent of HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler and copied contents of exchange method from HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler class. I am passing restTemplate bean name as message header and resolving it at the start of exchange method.

Is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "using single gateway" is already a wrong decision from design.

You probably need to think about having different `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` for those purposes. In your logic you can add then a router to decide to which HTTP Outbound Gateway to send a message.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/message-routing.html#messaging-routing-chapter